# Не могу получить данные запроса GET в request. В консоле пустая переменная

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, request

```
const request = require('request');

var cards;

request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users'    
   }, function (error, response, body) {
   if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    cards = body;
   }
 })

console.log(cards);
```

Но если вывести console.log(body), то данные есть.

Comment: Вы уже определитесь. Либо GET, либо body. У запросов GET нет тела

Comment: Если вывести console.log(body), то данные есть, но они не присваиваются в переменную.

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov тут body это уже тело ответа

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо :) Туплю